# Fill ViewBag with all loaded views and list them in _layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm using MVC 4.
I want to add automaticly (What means, do this in a framework part, which I can reuse in every project and not add something in every action manuely to the ViewBag) all loaded views (also partial views) that are loaded in a normal action lifecycle (Without ajax requests) to the ViewBag and list them in the _layout view.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Server should have access to folder's tree so you propably could try with simple checking this if you really need also partial view.